# Sort and join mongodb collections in python

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I need to know why my aggregation query is failing during testing.

The ***books*** collection looks like this,

```
_id: 573a13a6f29313caabd17bd5
title: "TinTin And the Picaros"
```

The ***comments*** collection looks like this,

```
_id: 5a9427648b0beebeb69579cc
name :"Andrea Le"
email :"andrea_le@fakegmail.com"
book_id : 573a1390f29313caabcd418c
text: "Rem officiis eaque repellendus amet eos doloribus. Porro dolor volupta..."
date: 2012-03-26 23:20:16.000
```

One book could have multiple comments. The book_id field in the comments collection and the _id field in the books collection link the two.

I need to retrieve the comments and sort by date. The aggregation i came up with is in the function get_book,

```
def get_book(id):
 books = db.books.aggregate([
            {
                '$lookup': {
                    'from': 'comments',
                    'let': {
                        'book_id': id
                    },
                    'pipeline': [
                        {
                            '$match': {
                                '$expr': {
                                    '$eq': [
                                        '$book_id', '$$book_id'
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            '$sort': {
                                'date': -1
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    'as': 'comments'
                }}]).next()

        return books
```

The test function is as follows,

```
def test_fetch_comments_for_book(client):
    book_id = "573a13a6f29313caabd17bd5"
    result = get_book(book_id)
    assert len(result.get('comments', [])) == 2
```

The test fails with the error,

```
 AssertionError: assert 0 == 2
```

I have a hunch its the way i am linking the parameter passed in the aggregation. Appreciate your input, Thank you.

Comment: Why you don't put the `id` from the collection iteself. `'let': {
                        'book_id': '$_id'
                    },`

Comment: Thanks, but in that case where will I link the id passed as the function parameter.

Comment: You should use `$match` stage at the start of the pipeline. `{ $match: { _id: id }}`

Comment: So I just have to add that. The rest of the pipeline remains the same ?

Comment: Its not working sadly. I am getting NameError: name '_id' is not defined when executing the test.